# Where is Location of Microsoft Edge Extension Folder that are installed from Microsoft Store?

Tags: microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

Where is the location of Microsoft Edge extensions folder when they are installed from Microsoft Store, in Windows 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since extensions are appx packages, try `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Packages`. Search for the folder starting with the extension name.

Edit: Actual source code is in the `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps`
You might need to change folder owner to yourself to gain access.

Answer (score 20):

In your edge browser go to edge://version/ page and locate the *Profile Path* there that would look something like `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Extensions`

Comment: You can use `about:version` in other Chromium-based browsers to get there as well.

Answer (score 10):

The source code is at `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Extensions\{{id}}`!

`{{id}}` is the id of the extension.

see it at `edge://extensions/` and enable developer mode and under the extension it says ID: {{id}}

Comment: There is a missing \ after C:\Users

Comment: Otherwise, confirmed this answer is valid as of the 'new/chromium' MS Edge as of version: 
 89.0.774.50 (Official build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 6):

Its located under

`C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Extensions`

Comment: Cannot physically find the `\Microsoft` folder under `%appdata%`, so had to manually type it in the path in the address bar to get there.

Answer (score 1):

C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge Dev\User Data\Profile 1\Extensions

Answer (score 1):

location is

```
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Extensions
```

Dir name is extension's id, you can find it at extension detail page's url.

Answer (score 1):

C:\Users\account name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Extensions

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When adding an answer to an older question with an accepted answer it is very important to point out what new aspect of the question your answer addresses. For example, does this path replace some of the others in other answers starting with a particular version of Edge?

Answer (score 0):

all the other answers are right.

Navigate to C:\users\(username)\appdata\local\microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Extensions, and search for the extension you are looking for, by finding it‘s same id.

or, look at C:\Program Files\WindowsApps. Use [Take ownership](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-take-ownership-to-explorer-right-click-menu-in-vista/) to gain access to that folder.(that also works for windows 10). Go to the bottom of the page to find the link to download the hack.

note: You can spot another file named "Program Files(x86)". You can use that as an alternative for deleting apps with control panel. That method deleted an heavy app, in just a few secs! It was obvious that it would take time by using control panel.